# How to list all false values in c++

Tags: c++

am new to c++ and am looking for a way to list all currently false values. e.g i have 30 bools, some false some true and need an easy way to list all the false ones.

```
 bool Monday9J, Monday10J, Monday11J, Monday12J, Monday1J, Monday2J, Monday3J, Monday4J; // Monday & Time (JEFF)
```

some of these values are set to 0, some to 1. looking for a way to display all the 0 ones

cout << display etc
Thanks
Dan

Comment: What do you mean you "have 30 bools"? Have in what form? What do you mean "list"? Where In what form do you want them to appear?

Comment: count how many false ones there are, and then output "false" that many times

Comment: `if (!bools[n]) print(bools[n])`

Comment: You need to show more code, and/or, be more clear in what you're asking.   You're going to need a loop...

Comment: Looking at that list of variables .... do you know what an array is?  One purpose of arrays is managing a collection of values, without having to use a set of names like var0, var1, var2, ......   var30.   Instead (in this case) simply declare an array named var with 31 elements, and access var[i] where i is between 0 and 30.

Answer (score 1):

Use array

```
bool monday[30];
for(int i=0;i<30;i++)
if(!monday[i])
std::cout<< "monday["<<i<<"]"<<std::endl;
```